# Why doesn't wireless work on Wubi 12.04 with a Broadcom BCM4312 card?

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I have recently set up ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop using the Wubi installer.  I am having a very difficult time setting up a wireless internet connection.  I am currently set up with an ethernet connection which I have used to download all new updates and to activate the Broadcom STA wireless driver.

I have tried several things in the terminal based on other people's posts: 
     `~$ rfkill list 

           0: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN 

           Soft blocked: no 

           Hard blocked: yes` 


`~$ rfkill unblock all`

It doesn't change anything.  I also tried rebooting and connecting to the internet on my Windows Vista OS, and it worked, so I know that the connection should not be hard blocked.  I have also tried installing b43 firmware (lp/phy version) that is supposed to work with my chip (BCM4312).  It seems to have no effect.

Then I tried: 
 
`~$ iwconfig 

lo        no wireless extensions.`

`eth1      IEEE 802.11  Access Point: Not-Associated`  
         `Link Quality:5  Signal level:0  Noise level:0` 
          `Rx invalid nwid:0  invalid crypt:0  invalid misc:0`

eth0      no wireless extensions.

This is my first time trying to work with ubuntu, so I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Also sorry this is poorly formatted. I'm having troubles with that too.

Answer (score -1):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1596061

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.